# frs and ntfrs tag merge request

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, retag-request

Can someone please merge [frs](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/frs) and [ntfrs](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ntfrs) tags? They both refer to the same component. I.e. NT file replication service.

[frs](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/frs) would be the preferred tag to remain.

Comment: Do you know what's its official name is? I'd probably call it [ntfrs] over [frs], but that's maybe just me. If I saw the [ntfrs] tag, that would click in my head what it was relating to before [frs] would, but again maybe just me.

Comment: Official name is FRS. ntfrs is the service name. Please see the FRS tag description as I updated it. Thanks.

Comment: [Mark](http://serverfault.com/users/7709/mark-henderson) did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now complete.

(we like to have answers on these so they don't show up as no answers..)